# ES6 : Create objects in a given format from array of key values

Tags: arrays, object, ecmascript-6, key-value

var result = {445: "L005.0", 455: "L006.0", 456: "L007.0", 457: "L008.0", 458: "L009.0", 459: "L027.0", 467: "L005.7", 580: "L001.0", 581: "L002.0", 587: "L003.0"};

From this "result", I want to output an object like this

```
        { 
            "445": {
                name: result[445],
                icon: "fa-search"
            },
            "455": {
                name: result[455],
                icon: "fa-search"
            },
            "456": { ... },
            "457": { ... },
          ...
          ...
        }
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to iterate over keys to construct new object o;

```
    let res={}; //initializing  
    
    for(let i of Object.keys(result))
    {
        res[i]={
              "name": result[i],
              "icon":"fa-seach"
             }
    }
  console.log(res) //to test
```

Comment: @TonyStack please remember to mark the answer as correct if it was useful for your problem or let me know if you need anything else